# How to make a single partition not mount automatically

Tags: usb-drive, partitioning, automount

I have a USB drive which has a data partition and a bootable Linux installed. The Linux installation is LUKS encrypted so it asks for password every time I insert the drive even though I don't even want to mount it.

I looked around and found the hidden flag but that apparently works for windows only. Is there a flag that makes Ubuntu not try to auto-mount the partition. If not, is there another way to make it not mount automatically? Preferably one where I modify the drive so it would work on every pc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was able to achieve this by flagging the partitions as esp, which is definitely a bad solution, but it works.